# Typo3 - Images aren't found on "sub paths" (no absolute path)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I wrote a Typo-3 template which is working fine the problem is that when I call a "sub path" the image links aren't found anymore.

```
/index.php: every thing works fine
/test/index.php: images aren't found anymore
```

The problem is that no image url is an absolute path whether from TypoScript or from fileadmin via component.

Is there a way to force absolute path use everywhere?

Comment: How are the image urls generated? Hard coded in the template or are using the [`uri.image`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Uri/Image.html#absolute) viewhelper?

Comment: @empiric its the same vor all images one is generated by TypoScript with IMG_RESOURCE and one is included in a normal text component over fileadmin. Also the images generated as preview for pdfs aren't displayed.

Comment: So you are integratong the image via the standard typo3 backend not a custom fluid template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use an extension to get nice URLs (`coolUri` or `realUrl`) so you get path segments for each page other than the root page.
So you have subfolders in your URL but always the index.php from your webroot is called.

Now you have images which by default are referenced relative to the working php script. As the working php script is `/index.php` a path to `fileadmin/img/image1.jpg` is correct.
But your browser thinks you are in path `/test` and requests an image `<domain>/test/fileadmin/img/image1.jpg`, which does not exist.

Either your browser needs to know which base to use for server pathes (setting base Url),

or (better) you provide absolute URLs for any resources. This can be done with a little typoscript configuration:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

Comment: `config.absRefPrefix = /` that's what I looked for thank you